# Does C++ support parameterized function for testing purpose?

Tags: c++

I have a lengthy unit test code snippet that I want to run for two functions. I am wondering if there's a way to do this without copy and paste the code and only change the function name?
Say the test code looks like

```
int main(){
    output1 = function(input1);
    assert output1 == answer1;
    output2 = function(input2);
    assert output2 == answer2;
    output3 = function(input3);
    assert output3 == answer3;
    ......
    outputN = function(inputN);
    assert outputN == answerN;
}
```

Now say I have two function func1 and func2. I want to ran literally the same test for func1 and func2. I am wondering if there's a neat way to do this in C++ without involving some test framework? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You aren't running the same test tho, you have input2 and output2. Is this the complete example or is there something more complex you have?

Comment: your question isnt quite clear. You should have included what the tests shoud look like for `func1` and `func2`. Anyhow you have answers for different interpretations and you can choose

Comment: I think he's trying to say that main is now the test for func1, now he wants to do the exact same test for func2 somehow.

Comment: @0xbaadf00d also my interpretation, but it also could be something else

Comment: Can we get some feedback? Did any of the answers work for you?

Comment: @0xbaadf00d Sorry for the delayed response. Thanks again for everyone's help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a function template:

```
template <typename F, typename R, typename Args...>
void test_func(F f, R&& r, Args&&... args) {

    auto output = f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    assert(output == std::forward<R>(r));

}
```

then use it like

```
test_func(&func1, answer1, input1);
test_func(&func2, answer2, input2);
...
```

Additional explanations:

- The parameters and return value are passed by [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references), then their [value categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) will be reserved when being passed to the function (with the usage of [`std::forward`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward)).
- The parameters is declared as [parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) then you can pass multiple ones with any types.

Comment: is serial voting of different answers on one question also considered as serial voting? I first wondered if there is something wrong with my answer, but when I saw a downvote on this one I knew what is going on here....

Comment: @idclev463035818 I think no. Serial voting is counted based on user, so...

Comment: i dont care for my rep, but a innocent user might get the impression that there is something wrong with your answer. +1 because this is the only answer that does exactly reproduce OPs code

Comment: @idclev463035818 Thanks, and I believe community will give the right judgement.

Comment: yep. Most fuzz and excitment is about the first 5 minutes of votes, but on the long run those votes really mean nothing

Comment: I just assumed his tests were simple integers or something. This goes way too far for the casual reader to even consider on the first read. Maybe you should point it out?

Comment: @0xbaadf00d Fine, added.

Answer (score 1):

C++ supports passing parameters to functions ;).

You can pass functions to functions. To keep it simple, I am assuming that all functions you want to test have the same signature. To avoid verbose syntax of function pointers I'd use a template:

```
template <typename F>
void test_function(F f, std::vector<input_type> input,std::vector<output_type> expected) {
      for (size_t i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i) {
          assert( f(input[i]) == expected[i]);
      }
}

int main() {
    test_function( func1, {1,2,3},{2,3,4} );
    test_function( func2, {1,2,3},{6,7,8} );
}
```

PS: From my own experience I can tell you that it isn't worth to put much work into hand-written test facilities. You will find yourself wanting more and more features that a test framework offers out of the box (eg logging test reports). [Googletest](https://github.com/google/googletest) is something I can recommend.

Comment: You might want to check that _input_ and _expected_ are of the same size?

Comment: @0xbaadf00d I didn't do that on purpose because I don't think such check should be placed down the call stack but rather at the very top when constructing `input` and `output`, hardcoding the values in the function calls was just to keep it simple

Answer (score 0):

A solution of C methed is to use fuction pointer. But I recommand lambda fuction pulished in c++11. u can use as follow:

```
template<typename Func>
void test(intput in, output out, Func func) {
    answer = func(in);
    assert(out == answer);

}

void main() {
    intput intput1;
    output output1;
    test(input1, output1, [&](intput in)->output{return func1(in)});
    test(input1, output1, [&](intput in)->output{return func2(in)});
}
```

After all, u should add compile para:**-std=c++11** while using g++ compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my new take, this should compile. It's built in layers so you can see how to expand each layer as you see fit. It doesn't work exactly as your example does, there are copies being made of your input data and there is no assignment operation for the output. You should take these into account and adjust accordingly (if required).

```
// Example program
#include <functional>
#include <assert.h>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

// function to test
int func1(int p_param)
{
  return p_param;
}

// function to test
int func2(int p_param)
{
  return p_param;
}

// Test runner base
template <typename TFunction, typename TInput, typename TOutput>
void test_runner(TFunction f, std::vector < std::pair<TInput, TOutput> > p_testparameters)
{
  for (auto pair : p_testparameters)
  {
    assert(f(pair.first) == pair.second);
  }
}

// Specific test 1
template <typename TFunction>
void test1(TFunction f)
{
  test_runner<TFunction, int, int>(f, { {1,1},{2,2},{3,3} });
}


// Specific test 2
template <typename TFunction>
void test2(TFunction f)
{
  test_runner<TFunction, int, int>(f, { {10,10},{20,20},{30,30} });
}

// Run tests for function
template <typename TFunction>
void runTests(TFunction f)
{
  test1(f);
  test2(f);
}

int main() {
  runTests(func1);
  runTests(func2);

  return 0;
}
```